# How can I customize the sort order for an NSArray of strings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsarray

I have a series of strings representing the following file names: `hello1(eng).txt`, `hello1(por).txt`, `hello1.txt`.  When I sort them using

```
NSArray *array = [filePaths sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

The order returned is `hello1(eng).txt, hello1(por).txt, hello1.txt`.  I would instead like to have this order, where the items in parentheses are returned last:  `hello1.txt, hello1(eng).txt, hello1(por).txt`.

How can I customize the sorting behavior to provide this ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sortedArrayUsingSelector:` tells the array to ask the individual objects it's trying to sort for the appropriate sort order. To provide your own, use one of the other `sortedArrayUsing…` functions. The easiest for your task is probably [sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction%3acontext%3a) which allows you to specify a plain old C function which does the comparison.

Another approach would be to use a category to add a sorting function to the NSString class, something along the lines of `compareInMyFavor:` and pass that as the selector for `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`.

Now that I think of it, the latter is probably the cleaner solution. Your call.

Comment: I'd much prefer sortedArrayUsingComparator: lets you pass a block instead of messing with defining the c function and context.